# Searching/Indexing SOLR documents with a quote in the field

Tags: solr

I'm using SOLR for search on an e-commerce site.

Many products contain a dimension in the description, using the " notation for inches, and the ' for feet.

So I have 2 questions:

1. What analyzer/tokenizer would I use to add that to the Index, and
2. Would a simple addition to synonyms.txt (inch => " feet => ') work?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. My preference was to use the `StandardTokenizer` but it strips the `'` and `"` and I could not find a way to add an exception.  This meant synonyms, which are post-tokenizer, would be useless for the task.  I searched for another tokenizer that would not strip the quotes and apostrophe but still be useful for "standard" tokenizing.  I came up empty.

The solution I ended up going with was to use a `charFilter` before the tokenizer to change the `"` and `'` to something else that was easier to work with.  I used the `PatternReplaceCharFilter` to achieve this.

Since I am using the `StandardTokenizer` on the index and the query, I decided to also do this text replacement on both.  In my case I wanted to be sure that the value was followed or preceded by white space.  You can adjust the regex to your particular needs.

I should note that I do have the synonyms set as well (from my prior, failed, efforts).  However, I am assuming that they are not playing a role in the case of these two characters, since they are being converted pre-tokenizer.

This also has a `PatternCaptureGroupFilter` to help better index things like 1x1mm or 2.5"x15"

Analyzer

```
    <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([\d\.]+)&quot;\s" replacement="$1 inch "/>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([\d\.]+)&apos;\s" replacement="$1 feet "/>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\s([\d\.]+)&quot;" replacement=" $1 inch"/>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\s([\d\.]+)&apos;" replacement=" $1 feet"/>

        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
        />
        <filter class="solr.PatternCaptureGroupFilterFactory" pattern=".*(([0-9\.]+([a-z&quot;&apos;]?)x[0-9\.]+)([a-z&quot;&apos;]?))\s*" preserve_original="true"/>           
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnNumerics="1" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" types="word-delim-special-chars.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([\d\.]+)&quot;\s" replacement="$1 inch "/>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([\d\.]+)&apos;\s" replacement="$1 feet "/>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\s([\d\.]+)&quot;" replacement=" $1 inch"/>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\s([\d\.]+)&apos;" replacement=" $1 feet"/>

        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
        />
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnNumerics="1" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" types="word-delim-special-chars.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
```

I am including the following for clarity and thoroughness, but I do not believe they are playing a role in the final result (related to the quote and apostrophe).

word-delim-special-chars.txt

```
" => ALPHA
' => ALPHA
. => ALPHANUM
_ => ALPHA
```

synonyms.txt

```
",inch,inches,in.
feet,ft,',ft.,foot
oz,ounce,ounces,oz.
mm,millimeter,mm.,millimeters,mms
by,x
gram,g,grams
cm,centimeter,centimeters
```